# Transferring audio through arduino. Formation of a parcel

Tags: simulink

I'm new here. I want to try streaming audio using arduino.
I have:

1. arduino
2. Radio module nrf24l01
3. Computer
4. Matlab program, arduinoIDE

I want to use a computer microphone, step by step ADC of the computer. But here's how to learn how to form sendings from this signal so that it can be sent through the arduino to the radio module, and then restored again on another computer?

Is there a tutorial video or theory? I would be very grateful, thank you!

Comment: hi. So, am I understanding you correctly, you're asking us how to encode the digital audio on your PC for transmission. That's the job of an *audio codec*; I think there's really many information on audio codecs if you start, e.g. with the wikipedia article. A key question is how much bits per second you can send. You should figure that out as a first step.

Comment: Step 1:
Thanks! You understood the question correctly.
Maximum speeds of my devices:
1. Radio module NGF24l01: 2,000,000 bits per second.
2. Arduino nano:
--- clock frequency of the microcontroller Atmega 328: 16,000,000 Hz. (if you use an external quartz resonator, then 20,000,000 Hz).
--- Serial port baud rate: 115,200,000 bits per second.

These are theoretical values.

What can I find out next?
I also read about audio codecs, as I understand there are not so many main ones, here they are:
WAVE (.wav)
OGG (.ogg)
FLAC (.flac)
AU (.au)
AIFF (.aiff, .aif)
AIFC
MP3
MPEG-4 AAC

Comment: there's *extremely* many audo codecs; what you list are some of the popular ones for audio in files on computers (FLAC, OGG, MP3), some popular in modern standards as well as on computer files (MPEG-4 AAC), and a couple of things that aren't codecs but just container formats (.wav, .aiff).